# Do flagged answers get deleted?

Tags: support

I'm referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293035?tab=votes#tab-top

One user posted 2 *definitely* spam answers and I flagged them both. (and downvoted them to boot!)

When will they get removed?

Edit: *He-he... posted a link to the wrong question.*

Comment: @ChrisF: Posted the wrong link... see embarrassing explanation above.

Comment: Comment about original link removed.

Comment: Isn't there a 48-hr limit on flags? We should get rid of these sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each offensive or spam flag, the original poster receives a -2 reputation penalty.

When the post has accumulated a total of six flag (any combination of spam and offensive), the post is chowned to the Community user, locked, and deleted, and the poster receives a -100 reputation penalty (giving a total penalty of -112).

However, I think this entire sum is refunded upon a reputation recalc, which renders the whole exercise somewhat pointless if we ever move to regular recalcs  (please someone correct me if I am wrong -- do flags show up on the reputation audit?).

Comment: Not sure about the -2 hit, though it effectively works that way when checking to see if a question should show on the front page.

Comment: I believe reputation lost to downvotes and spam/offensive deletions is never refunded even if the post is deleted. The -2 from each individual flag I'm not sure about; if the flags age away, is the rep refunded?

Comment: @random: if you refresh the page after flagging a post as spam, you will see that the user's rep has gone down by 2.

Comment: Always thought that that was due to some 10kers seeing the flagged post and downvoting justly.

Comment: the variable here is that the downvotes come from user -1, and those votes disappear if the post does not reach the threshold. The actual final offensive vote, if it *does* reach the threshold, is immutable and permanent and always counts.

Answer (score 1):

They will be automatically deleted once they accumulate six spam/offensive votes. Also, a moderator might look through the flagged posts and delete the answers manually before that.

Comment: Could one of the moderators do that please?